# C++ code to convert a fraction to binary

Tags: c++, stl, floating-point, double, precision

I just wrote the following C++ code in order to convert a fractional number into its corresponding binary format.

```
double get_decimal_part(double num) {
   long x = static_cast<long>(num);
   return (num - static_cast<double>(x));
}

long get_real_part(double num) {
   return static_cast<long>(num);
}

string fraction_to_binary(double num) {
   string decimal_binary = "";
   double decimal_part = get_decimal_part(num);
   while ( decimal_part > 0 ) {
      double temp = decimal_part * 2;
      if ( get_real_part(temp) == 0 ) decimal_binary += "0";
      else                            decimal_binary += "1";
      decimal_part = get_decimal_part(temp); 
   }
   return decimal_binary;
}

int main() {
   cout << "3.50 - " << fraction_to_binary(3.50) << endl;
   cout << "3.14 - " << fraction_to_binary(3.14) << endl;
}
```

The output would be :-

```
3.50 - 1
3.14 - 001000111101011100001010001111010111000010100011111
```

I'd have the following questions regarding the same :-

1. In the case if "3.50", my implementation would give "1" as the output -- how can I go about modifying my implementation in order to account for the trailing "0" in 3.50?
2. If there were any library functions that could help me get the precision of a floating point number? I'm guessing I could use that information to modify my implementation.

[EDIT]
I also tried using the following to convert a float to a string but it wouldnt help either.

```
   stringstream ss;
   ss << my_float;
   cout << string(ss.str()) << endl;
```

Comment: 1) You mean, account for the 20 trailing zeroes in 3.5? 2) Have you tested with negative numbers? 3) Why convert to long to get the fractional part? This will fail for very large numbers.

Comment: For the trailing `0`, you will need to handle your number as a string, as the numeric representation will not contain trailing zeros

Comment: @emartel I had tried that(I've made an edit to the question) -- do you have any suggestions on that? Thanks.

Comment: @uki your `my_float` already lost the trailing zeros

Comment: @MrLister 1) Yes 2) No, but I'll look into that right away. 3) I just assumed it'd be better than using "int". Should I be using another data type, say, double?

Comment: @uki Yes, use double. And `floor`.

Comment: What range of double your function should work with? Example 1.0e300 and 1.0e-300 might lead to some trouble...

Comment: How exactly would you account for the trailing zero in 3.140? What would your program output? Also, your function names are misleading, call them `get_fractional_part` and `get_integral_part`.

Comment: @MrLister 3.5 is actually 11.1000... (base 2) on my machine.  With either an infinite number of trailing zeros, or 49 trailing zeros, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: @MrLister And he shouldn't be using `floor`, but `modf`.  There is a library function which does exactly what he wants.

Comment: @JamesKanze Sorry, yes. Upvoting your answer out of penance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before answering your specific questions, what's wrong with
`modf` for this?

With regards to your specific questions:

1. What trailing `"0"`?  You're talking about a text
   representation here.  Inside the machine, `"3.5"` and `"3.50"`
   correspond to the same number, and have the same representation.
2. There is a library function which returns the precision of a
   floating point number: `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits`
   (except that it isn't a function, but a constant).  But if you
   want to break a number down into its integral and whole number
   parts, `modf` fits the bill exactly.  And unlike your code, will
   actually work, for all values of `double`.

### EDIT:

Looking closer at the larger picture of what you are trying to
do: my approach would be to use `frexp` to extract the base 2
exponent, then `ldexp` to scale the number into the range
`[0.5...1)` Then loop `std::numeric_limits<double>::digits`
times, each time multiplying by `2`, and checking that: if the
results of the multiplication are less than 1, then insert a 0
digit; otherwise, insert a 1 digit and subtract 1.  (Note
that all of the above actions will be exact if the machine
floating point is base 2, or a power of 2.)